# visual C# como solucionar el guardado de mi output

Tags: c#, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me deja guardar el id auto incrementable. 
¿Qué hago?

```
 public string insertar(DRegistro_Salida registro_salida)
    {
        string rpta = "";
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection();

        try
        {

            sqlCon.ConnectionString = conexion.Cn;
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlcmd.CommandText = "spinsertar_registro_salida";
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcmd.Connection = sqlCon;

            SqlParameter parid_salida = new SqlParameter();
            parid_salida.ParameterName = "@Id_salida";
            parid_salida.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            parid_salida.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(parid_salida);

            SqlParameter parcentro = new SqlParameter();
            parcentro.ParameterName = "@Centro";
            parcentro.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            parcentro.Size = 100;
            parcentro.Value = registro_salida.Centro;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(parcentro);

            SqlParameter parid_pendencia = new SqlParameter();
            parid_pendencia.ParameterName = "@Id_dependencia";
            parid_pendencia.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            parid_pendencia.Value = registro_salida.Id_dependencia;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(parid_pendencia);

            SqlParameter parIdempleado = new SqlParameter();
            parIdempleado.ParameterName = "@Id_empleado";
            parIdempleado.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            parIdempleado.Value = registro_salida.Id_empleado;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(parIdempleado);

            SqlParameter parid_cliente = new SqlParameter();
            parid_cliente.ParameterName = "@Id_cliente";
            parid_cliente.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            parid_cliente.Value = registro_salida.Id_cliente;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(parid_cliente);

            SqlParameter pardescripcion = new SqlParameter();
            pardescripcion.ParameterName = "@Descripcion";
            pardescripcion.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            pardescripcion.Size = 2000000;
            pardescripcion.Value = registro_salida.Descripcion;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(pardescripcion);

            SqlParameter parmarca = new SqlParameter();
            parmarca.ParameterName = "@Marca";
            parmarca.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            parmarca.Size = 50;
            parmarca.Value = registro_salida.Marca;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(parmarca);


            SqlParameter parequipo = new SqlParameter();
            parequipo.ParameterName = "@Equipo";
            parequipo.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            parequipo.Size = 50;
            parequipo.Value = registro_salida.Equipo;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(parequipo);


            SqlParameter parelemento = new SqlParameter();
            parelemento.ParameterName = "@Elemento";
            parelemento.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            parelemento.Size = 50;
            parelemento.Value = registro_salida.Elemento;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(parelemento);


            SqlParameter parserie = new SqlParameter();
            parserie.ParameterName = "@Serie";
            parserie.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            parserie.Size = 50;
            parserie.Value = registro_salida.Serie;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(parserie);

            SqlParameter parmodelo = new SqlParameter();
            parmodelo.ParameterName = "@Modelo";
            parmodelo.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            parmodelo.Size = 50;
            parmodelo.Value = registro_salida.Modelo;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(parmodelo);


            SqlParameter parfecha_Salida = new SqlParameter();
            parid_salida.ParameterName = "@Fecha_salida";
            parid_salida.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date;
            parid_salida.Value = registro_salida.Fecha_salida;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(parfecha_Salida);

            SqlParameter parfecha_entrega = new SqlParameter();
            parfecha_entrega.ParameterName = "@Fecha_entrega";
            parfecha_entrega.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date;
            parfecha_entrega.Value = registro_salida.Fecha_entrega;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(parfecha_entrega);


            SqlParameter parmotivo = new SqlParameter();
            parmotivo.ParameterName = "@Motivo";
            parmotivo.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            parmotivo.Size = 2000000;
            parmotivo.Value = registro_salida.Motivo;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(parmotivo);


            SqlParameter parestado = new SqlParameter();
            parestado.ParameterName = "@Estado";
            parestado.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            parestado.Size = 100;
            parestado.Value = registro_salida.Estado;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(parestado);

            SqlParameter parfecha_devulucion = new SqlParameter();
            parfecha_devulucion.ParameterName = "@Fecha_devolucion";
            parfecha_devulucion.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date;
            parfecha_devulucion.Value = registro_salida.Fecha_devolucion;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(parfecha_devulucion);



            rpta = sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 ? "OK" : "no se ingreso el registro";


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rpta = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Open) sqlCon.Close();
        }

        return rpta;
    }
```

Procedimiento almacenado:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[spinsertar_registro_salida]
@Id_salida int output,
@Centro varchar(100),
@Id_dependencia int,
@Id_empleado int,
@Id_cliente int,
@Descripcion varchar(max),
@Marca varchar(50),
@Equipo varchar(50),
@Elemento varchar(50),
@Serie varchar(50),
@Modelo varchar(50),
@Fecha_salida date,
@Fecha_entrega date,
@Motivo varchar(max),
@Estado VARCHAR(100),
@Fecha_devolucion date
as

insert into Registro_Salida(centro,id_dependencia,id_empleado,id_cliente,descripcion,marca,equipo,elemento,serie,modelo,fecha_salidaa,fecha_entrega,motivo,estado,fecha_devolucion)
values(@Centro,@Id_dependencia,@Id_empleado,@Id_cliente,@Descripcion,@Marca,@Equipo,@Elemento,@Serie,@Modelo,@Fecha_salida,@Fecha_entrega,@Motivo,@Estado,@Fecha_devolucion )
SELECT @Id_salida = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86608/discussion-on-question-by-darwin-visual-c-como-solucionar-el-guardado-de-mi-out).

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que asignar el parametro de salida en el procedure

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[spinsertar_registro_salida]
@Id_salida int output,
@Centro varchar(100),
@Id_dependencia int,
@Id_empleado int,
@Id_cliente int,
@Descripcion varchar(max),
@Marca varchar(50),
@Equipo varchar(50),
@Elemento varchar(50),
@Serie varchar(50),
@Modelo varchar(50),
@Fecha_salida date,
@Fecha_entrega date,
@Motivo varchar(max),
@Estado VARCHAR(100),
@Fecha_devolucion date
as

insert into Registro_Salida(centro,id_dependencia,id_empleado,id_cliente,descripcion,marca,equipo,elemento,serie,modelo,fecha_salidaa,fecha_entrega,motivo,estado,fecha_devolucion)
values(@Centro,@Id_dependencia,@Id_empleado,@Id_cliente,@Descripcion,@Marca,@Equipo,@Elemento,@Serie,@Modelo,@Fecha_salida,@Fecha_entrega,@Motivo,@Estado,@Fecha_devolucion )

SELECT @Id_salida = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

para luego desde c# poder recuperarlo

```
 var rowAffected = sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

 var id = (int)parid_salida.Value;

 rpta = rowAffected == 1 ? "OK" : "no se ingreso el registro";
```

[How to return Output parameter from Stored Procedure in ASP.Net using C# and VB.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-return-Output-parameter-from-Stored-Procedure-in-ASPNet-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Ademas puedes reducir mucho el codigo si usaras

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conexion.Cn);
sqlCon.Open();

SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("spinsertar_registro_salida", sqlCon);
sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Id_salida", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlcmd.Parameters["@Id_salida"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Centro", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = registro_salida.Centro;
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Id_dependencia", SqlDbType.Int).Value = registro_salida.Id_dependencia;

//resto parametros
```

puedes reducir 4 o 5 lineas a solo una, no necesitas asignar todo en propiedades

Comment: Estás seguro de que el error que le da es por no dar valor al parámetro de salida en el procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: Es un error, solo es cuestión de que pruebe puede ser la causa.

Comment: no puedo probarlo, pero si, teniendo la definicion del codigo c# y del procedure es el unico punto que falta para cerrar correctamente el uso del parametro

Comment: Yo es que tengo dudas la verdad. A ver si el OP lo aclara...

Comment: puse la respuesta porque queria mostrar el codigo completo tanto procedure como c# y desde un comentario la verdad poner codigo queda ilegible, sino es la solucion la elimino

Comment: le intente pero me sigue el error

Comment: una duda, intentaste realizar un rebuild del codigo? quizas hacer un clear, cerrar el VS volver abrirlo y recompilar, solo para forzar que recompile a vece sucede que se queda ejecutando codigo desactualizado, porque salvo la asignacion del parametro de salida no veo otra cosa incorrecta

Comment: Si en vez de utilizar `SELECT @Id_salida = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, por que no intentan con  `SET @Id_salida = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: muchas gracias, todavía me sale el mismo error

Comment: @LeandroTuttini me puedes hacer el favor de explicarme bien como es el rebuild ?

Comment: seria usar esta opcion del VS  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/838411

Comment: sigue igual @LeandroTuttini

Comment: podrias editar la pregunta y colocar el codigo tal cual lo tienes ? la verdad esta muy raro, que pasa si al procedure le quitas el parametro output ? por supuesto en el codigo tambien comentas ese parametro, a ver si cambia de mensaje